# How to stop animation after sometime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, settimeout

I am trying out the snow-fall animation. I want to stop it after for e.g. 5 seconds. I have current add the `animate` between `setTimeOut`, somehow there's no effect. What am I missing here?

Current code:

```
function fallingSnow() {

   var snowflake;
   snowflake = $('<div class="snowflakes"></div>');

   $('#snowZone').prepend(snowflake);
   snowX = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#site').width() / 4);
   snowSpd = Math.floor(Math.random() + 50000);

   snowflake.css({
       'left': snowX + 'px'
   });

   setTimeout(function(){
      snowflake.stop().animate({
          top: "700px",
          opacity: "5",
      }, snowSpd, function () {
          $(this).remove();
          fallingSnow();
      })
  },5000);
}

timer = Math.floor(Math.random() + 1000);

window.setInterval(function () {
    fallingSnow();
}, timer);
```

---

### UPDATE: AFTER UTILIZING @Kyojimaru's answer.

```
snowflake.animate({
        top: "700px",
        opacity: "5",
    }, 5000, function () {
        $(this).remove();           

      if(!end) {
        fallingSnow();
        window.setTimeout(function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
        end = true;
        }, 5000);
      }
    }                          
   );
```

- [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bonCodigo/5pm1yLtv/7/)

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because your `setInterval` never stopped from calling `fallingSnow`, try changing your code to this

```
var firstCall = false;
var interval, timeout;
function fallingSnow() {

   var snowflake;
   snowflake = $('<div class="snowflakes"></div>');

   $('#snowZone').prepend(snowflake);
   snowX = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#site').width() / 4);
   snowSpd = Math.floor(Math.random() + 50000);

   snowflake.css({
       'left': snowX + 'px'
   });

   if(!firstCall) {
       timeout = setTimeout(function(){
           clearInterval(interval);
       },5000);
       firstCall = true;
   }
}

timer = Math.floor(Math.random() + 1000);

interval = setInterval(function () {
    fallingSnow();
}, timer);
```

basically what you need is clearing the interval that has been set  for the `function fallingSnow()` using `clearInterval` only on the first time the function is called using `setTimeout`

here's the other example about it with what you want to do : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z5cx1n9r/)

and here's what probably happen to you now : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z5cx1n9r/1/)

### EDIT

based on your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bonCodigo/5pm1yLtv/) ( need to add `jQuery` and `snowflakes` css `width and height` to anything beside 0px )

your problem is you declare in the script as

```
var firstTime = false;
```

but checking it with

```
if (!firstCall)
```

so you need to change `var firstTime = false;` to `var firstCall = false;`

the other problem arise from this code here

```
snowflake.animate({
    top: "700px",
    opacity: "5",
}, snowSpd, function () {
    $(this).remove();
    fallingSnow();
});
```

which call the `fallingSnow();` function again when animate finished, thus the snow is never stop falling, so you need to check if the the `setTimeout` have already clear the interval or not, you need to change your code to this

```
snowflake.animate({
    top: "700px",
    opacity: "5",
}, snowSpd, function () {
    $(this).remove();
    if(!end) {
        fallingSnow();
    }
});

if (!firstCall) {
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
        end = true;
    }, 5000);
    firstCall = true;
}
```

and add `var end = false;` in the start with `firstCall`

here's the working one : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5pm1yLtv/6/)

Comment: @bonCodigo I've got where the problem arise, the snow not showing because you declare the width and height to 0px, and you check for firstCall but you declare it as firstTime in the first line, and when it's finished animating, you called the `fallingSnow` function again, if you want it to stop all snow from falling after 5s here's the working one http://jsfiddle.net/5pm1yLtv/6/ (you need to change the snowspeed again, I put it to 500 to test only)

Comment: Your edit is working +1. I am trying understand why we need to two `if` statement before accepting as the answer. In my opinion, I should be able to add `setTimeOut` to this line `if(!end) {
        fallingSnow();
    }`. According to my original post, isn't this concept `snowflake.stop().` correct? Why can't I clear the `interval` within animate?

Comment: @bonCodigo yes, you can put it inside `if(!end)` to make it shorter, but then the setTimeout will be called as many times as the total of snowflakes occured rather then just once on the initial. for your original post using `snowflake.stop()`, it work's, but for the `animate` to the current snowflakes only, but then you reapply the `animate`, so it start's again. And the last one, you can't clear the `interval` within the `animate`, because it's basically not an `interval`, it's like a `callback on finish animating`

Comment: You are absolute right in terms of *looping* `setTimeOut`unnecessarily. Thanks for explaining the loop-holes in my code and reasoning behind our code. Very well and your final code is still the most suitable in terms of optimization. Arigato Gosaimazu =) Cheers!